# node.js parallel requests are crashing node app - can't render headers

Tags: node.js, express

Ways to replicate the problem,

A. continuously refresh the browser (cmd+r) and then the app crashes with the following message

B. run mocha test suite, inside I'm using npm module request for http request and all of them pass, however as soon as I send another request in parallel using postman while the tests are running, then the app crashes with the following message.

```
http.js:731
throw new Error('Can\'t render headers after they are sent to the client.'
      ^
Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._renderHeaders (http.js:731:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (http.js:1152:20)
    at puremvc.define.signInWithCredentialsSuccess (eval at include     (/Library/WebServer/Documents/FICO/fico-node/app.js:3:32), <anonymous>:31:18)
```

the code referenced

```
signInWithCredentialsSuccess: function(request, response, authToken) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})
    response.end(this.mustache.render(this.successTemplate, {authToken: authToken}));
},
```

It's an express application combined with puremvc, so architecture is a bit different, for instance after app.get, the request and response are passed around to different decoupled modules and functions who accomplish their tasks and simply end the response by writing some output and then the process is repeated again for each subsequent request using new response/request objects passed.

I assume that I should be getting a new request and response object for each request but the error message confuses that for some reason the app.get is giving me a reference to an old response object which was already used to sent the information down to the client that's why it's refusing to modify the headers.

my node version is 0.10.32

please advise

Comment: You will have to show more of the code flow.  The problem is likely upstream of the code you're showing here.

Comment: I wish if I could but they are like 15-20 files, put simply consider a scenario if request and response are passed around different js modules, should it affect anything? are my response headers correct?

Comment: You should post a complete, minimal, reproducible piece of code that demonstrates the problem if you are not able to show any more existing relevant code.

Comment: We've seen this issue happen many times before and it is always because you're trying to write headers to a response that is already done.  Why that is in your code - we have no idea because you disclose no code that might show that.  It is often because of wrong handling of async responses or in your case, it could be errors in passing around the response object or some combination of both.  Not much else we can say without seeing relevant code.

Comment: C'mon man, show us your code. Everyone is doing it...

Comment: @jfriend00 I created a minimalist example and it worked fine, I believe it's wrong handling of async responses, please have a look at this file where I believe have several async operations http://jsfiddle.net/smartdev101/qmwhzfgk/

Comment: Please describe in words what the `getRecord()` method is supposed to be doing and the exact sequence of operations you expect.  FYI, complicated code with ZERO explanatory comments in it is never considered a good practice.

Comment: I don't see anything new in the jsFiddle.

Comment: sorry about that http://jsfiddle.net/smartdev101/cd58kca0/

Comment: guess what, checking if(!response.headersSent) { is making it work but I'm not sure where the problem is lying, and with simple console.log shows, on average 2 out of 10 hits had headers set already.